# Stripes Framework

Tags: java, eclipse, stripes

I am using Eclipse with Java 1.6.  I was wondering what the preliminary steps were to set up the Stripes framework.  (What do we do with the .jar file?)

I don't understand the basics of the framework, as I have thoroughly searched for a clear explanation (other then the Stripes website).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official [Quick Start Guide](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Quick+Start+Guide) provides a step by step guide to get you up and running with Stripes (the guide covers basic configuration and the development of your first Stripes application).

If you don't understand the instructions, then I suggest to follow @seanizer's advice and  start with the Java EE tutorial on the [web tier](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html) first. You really need to get basics skills before going further. Don't put the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds to me like you are missing the fundamentals of java web development. Maybe you should read the servlet chapter of the [Sun Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/), especially the bit about [web modules](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html):

**Sun Java EE Tutorial: [The Web Tier](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html)**

Basically you neet to create a WAR archive, where the stripes jar lies in the directory `WEB-INF/lib`. To wrap the WAR, you can either use IDE methods (e.g. in eclipse) or specilized build tools like Maven (here is an old but still valid Article about [web development with maven](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/03/01/building-web-applications-with-maven-2.html), there is also a good online [maven book from Sonatype](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/public-book.html), but I wouldn't know where to point you at, there's not really a web tutorial in there).

Answer (score 2):

There is an really excellent short(!) book on Stripes that covers all aspects:

**[Stripes: ...and Java Web Development Is Fun Again](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356212)**

by *Frederic Daoud* (*Pragmatic Programmers*)

Comment: This book is awesome. Frederic is a great author who explains and walks the reader the very clear, well though through, and insightful examples and provides insight into the mechanics and overall concepts of Stripes and web development in general.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest release of Stripes jar, add it to you pom if you are using Maven else add it to your project library.
2. Add few initial configurations, you can get from the [Stripes Quick Start Guide](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Quick+Start+Guide).

Comment: The Stripes Quick Start Guide link seems to have gone away.  Is there an updated source for the most recent version of this information?

Comment: Found it. It looks like the most recent Stripes info is here: http://www.stripesframework.org.